How to pass data from arrow function in service to parent component in Angular
how can I pass data from service to component? I have such code in component:
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signalrService.startConnection();
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.signalrService.askServerListener();
    }, 2000)
  }

In SignalrService it looks like this:
  askServerListener(){
    this.hubConnection.on("Send", (msg) =>{
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }

I don't know how can I use my "msg" in component.

you can do this in the SignalRService class
 askServerListener() {
    this.hubConnection.on("Send", (msg: string) => {
      console.log(msg);
      this.messageSubject.next(msg); // Emits the message through the Subject
    });
  }

and expose the Observable to the component you want to use it
getMessage() {
    return this.messageSubject.asObservable();  component
  }

while in your component you can subscribe to the data this way
 this.signalrService.getMessage().subscribe((msg: string) => {
      console.log('Message received in component: ', msg);
    });

This code can be registered in the ngOnInit method

The way I would handle this would be to make your this.signalrService.startConnection() method return an Observable, specifically a Subject, and subscribe to this Observable.
i.e.
The Component:
@Component(...)
export class TheComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
destroyed$ = new Subject();
ngOnInit() {
    this.signalrService.startConnection$()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
        .subscribe((msg) => {
            ...
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroyed$.next(true);
    }
}

And the Service:
@Injectable(...)
export class SignalrService {
    currentMessageStream$: Subject<Msg> = new Subject();

    startConnection$(): Observable<Msg> {
        ...
        return currentMessageStrem$;
    }
}

Then anytime you want to send another message from the service to the component, in the service you would call:
currentMessageStream$.next(theMessage);

This question and answer may be helpful: Passing Data from Service to Component
